# belongs_to has_many busca informação na tabela

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho 2 tabelas: `user` e `contact`, e criei uma terceira para ligação entre as duas: `user_contact`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many:user_contacts
end
    class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many:user_contacts
end
class UserPaciente < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to:user
    belongs_to:paciente
end
```

Tenho este `controller`:

```
  def index
        @contacts = UserContact.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end
```

E esta `view`:

```
  <tbody>
        <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= contact.contact.id %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Já tentei de tudo, mas não funciona, como posso buscar a lista de `contacts` do `current_user`?

Comment: "Tenho 3 tabelas" mas falas de 2... (?) E "não funciona" não é uma descrição adequada... o que acontece? Você pode [edit] a pegunta para acrescentar mais detalhes.

Comment: já editei, espero estar mais explícito

Answer (score 2):

Tente usando `has_many through`:

```
class User
  has_many :contacts, through :user_contact
end

class Contact
  has_many :users, through :user_contact
end

class UserContact
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

`contacts_controller`:

```
def index
  @contacts = current_user.contacts
end
```

Não se esqueça de ler a [sessão de associações no guia oficial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).